# Where can I farm Boar Prime in warframe?

Tags: warframe

Anyone knows where can I farm "Boar Prime" Blueprint and the part for the item. I know its in void mission but if you guys can give more detail for which void mission drop it and how many % do I have to get it per mission.

If anyone knows about this I would be glad to thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

As of the latest spreadsheet posted to reddit, the Boar Prime may be farmed in Void Mobile Defense missions.  The sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AkvYeRRKpi05dHF6YkFLX2NxUlZDRjNSTXdfWmhMcGc&gid=15), and [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/Warframe/comments/1mt94s/1010_raw_reward_tables/) is the original /r/warframe post for the drop table.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

As per the [wiki](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Boar_Prime):

- Blueprint

  - Void **Tower I/III** Mobile Defense / **Tower III** Survival
- Barrel

  - Void **Tower III** Mobile Defense
- Receiver

  - Void **Tower I/II** Capture / **Tower I** Mobile Defense
- Stock

  - Void **Tower II** Mobile Defense